# Matlab: Put each line of a text file in a separate array

Tags: matlab, cell, fopen

I have a file like the following

```
 10158 18227 2055 24478 25532 
 12936 14953 17522 17616 20898 24993 24996 
 26375 27950 32700 33099 33496 3663 
 ...
```

I would like to put each line in an array in order to access elements of each line separately.
I used cell arrays but it seems to create a 1 by 1 array for each cell element:

```
fid=fopen(filename)
nlines = fskipl(fid, Inf)
frewind(fid);
cells = cell(nlines, 1);
for ii = 1:nlines
    cells{ii} = fscanf(fid, '%s', 1);
end
fclose(fid);
```

when I access `cells{ii}`  I get all values in the same element and I can't access the list values

Comment: Just `str2num` each line before putting it in the cell matrix, `str2num` converts a string of numbers with spaces to a numerical array. See my answer for an example. Also avoid using `i` aa dn `j` s a variable names in matlab as they are reserved for `sqrt(-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `fscanf(fid, '%s', 1);` is telling matlab to read the line a single string. You will still have to convert it to an array of numbers:

```
for ii = 1:nlines
    cells{ii} = str2num(fscanf(fid, '%s', 1));
end
```

Comment: I used that because I don't know the number of elements in each line

Comment: @tuxworker See edit for how to convert the string into an array of numbers

Comment: @tuxworker Is the second method successful? If it is I will delete the first method?

Comment: yes But I think 'fgetl' should be used instead of fscanf to get the whole line content correctly.

Answer (score 2):

A shorter solution would be reading the file with `textscan`:

```
fid = fopen(filename, 'r');
C = cellfun(@str2num, textscan(fid, '%s', 'delimiter', ''), 'Uniform', false);
fclose(fid);
```

The resulting cell array `C` is what you're looking for.